# How to send a RenderedImage as input to a Process

Tags: java, bufferedimage, processbuilder, jbig2

I am able to compress an image file using the jbig2.exe encoder.
 
I can easily execute the **`jbig2.exe`** from the command line **`ex: >jbig2.exe`** **`C:\images\image.jpg.`**
 
However I am trying to write a Java code that will invoke the `jbig2.exe` using a `ProcessBuilder`.
 
Now the image I have is a RenderedImage and I am getting confused over how to give it as input to the ProcessBuilder. Ex :

```
void encoder_to_jbig2(RenderedImage image) throws Exception{ 

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.command("jbig2.exe");
Process p = pb.start();
OutputStream os = p.getOutputStream();
```

Thanks.

Comment: convert RenderedImage to byte array and write the byte arrays to OutputStream to create the image file. Then use that path in the ProcessBuilder command method.

Comment: What input does the `jbig2.exe` command take? Can it read bytes from the console, or does it need a file input? Does it support "raw" pixels, or do you need some file format?